# .Net Core AspNetCoreHostingModel what does it mean?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

By this link, you can read about ASP.NET Core Module

> To configure an app for in-process hosting, add the property to the app's project file with a value of InProcess (out-of-process hosting is set with OutOfProcess)

I've read several times but I don't understand what it's mean?

When I must use OutOfProcess and when InProcess?

Pros and cons these models?

What to rely on when making a decision?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is referring to how IIS is hosting your app (web.config).

***InProcess*** : IIS host the app (w3wp.exe or iisexpress.exe)

***OutOfProcess***: Kestrel host the app, IIS is a proxy to kestrel.

More [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2) on how to configure and what to keep in mind for each one when using.

'InProcess' has significant better performance according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

To configure **InProcess** add web config with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables />
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

For **OutOfProcess**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess">
        <environmentVariables />
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

when you will generate the build in my-api folder or plain publish to your server with:

```
dotnet publish -o my-api -c release
```

will take care if your %LAUNCHER_PATH% and %LAUNCHER_ARGS%.

What you are referring in initial question possibly is about .csproj config that dictate how app runs locally, default is **InProcess**

Comment: Perhaps at the time this was posted the default was OutOfProcess, but now (in VisualStudio2019 community at least) the hosting model says "Default (In Process)"