# ASP.NET Core API Deployment on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Windows Server not Reflecting Code Changes Despite Successful Builds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, windows-server-2019

I've set up an AWS infrastructure that involves an EC2 instance running Windows Server 2019, managed by AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have an ASP.NET Core API application that I am trying to deploy to this server using an automated pipeline involving AWS CodeBuild for the build process and AWS CodeDeploy for deployment.

Here is my buildspec.yml:

```
        version: 0.2
        
        phases:
          install:
        runtime-versions:
        
        dotnet: 7.0
        
          pre_build:
        
        commands:
        
        - dotnet restore .\project\foo.csproj
        
          build:
        
        commands:
        
        - dotnet build .\project\foo.csproj
        
          post_build:
        
        commands:
        
        - dotnet publish -c Release -o .\ .\project\foo.csproj
        
        artifacts:
        
          files:
        
        - '**/*'
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\foo.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

foo.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RootNamespace>foo</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(RunConfiguration)' == 'https' " />
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(RunConfiguration)' == 'http' " />
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <AssemblyName>foo</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.2.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="2.2.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Web.config" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I am encountering an issue where, despite having successful build and deployment processes (as indicated by Elastic Beanstalk's health status and logs), the code updates aren't being reflected on the server. This discrepancy persists even though I am pushing the new changes to my repository and seeing a success message from Elastic Beanstalk.

Further, I have run and tested the project locally, where it operates perfectly fine. This leads me to believe that the problem lies in my deployment configuration or process rather than the application code itself.

I'm at a loss as to why my updates aren't taking effect on the server, despite no apparent errors in the build and deployment process. Can anyone provide insight or suggestions on what might be going wrong or what I could check to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try troubleshooting If you are hosting your website on IIS in ec2:

1. try adding this to your .csproj: `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>`
   [OutOfProcess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762322/net-core-aspnetcorehostingmodel-what-does-it-mean)
2. Further you can clear your cache or try using different browser in your ec2
3. Look for possible warnings when you are building project in your local machine